# Field within content type does not publish

Tags: entities, nodes

this is possibly a terribly stupid question, but I just cannot find the solution:
I am trying to make small changes to a Drupal 6.26 site and, although the field is there within the list in the content type and I have copied all settings I could find from similar field that is working fine, it just would not publish on the site.

where do I need to look, what am I missing???

A pointer would be so much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: In your Content type check -> Manage display.

Comment: Thank you J Sinha! Is 'Display Fields' the same, since I cannot find 'Manage Display'.